# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'file:inbound-channel-adapter'

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration while I am trying file input channel adopter I got the following error.I attached the pom.xml, app-config.xml and supporting Java class. I think some where some attribute which is mandatory is missing.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 26 in XML document from class path resource [app-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 99; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'file:inbound-channel-adapter'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at filetransfer.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:17)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 99; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'file:inbound-channel-adapter'.
```

Following in my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>org.ccc</groupId>
        <artifactId>filetransfer</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->``
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <start-class>filetransfer.DemoApplication</start-class>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-gemfire</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hornetq</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-event</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-bitronix</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

my app-config.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:tool="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
           xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inboundFiles" 
         auto-create-directory="true" id="inboundFiles"
            auto-startup="true" filename-regex="test[0-9]+\.txt"
            directory="file:C:\dev\springbatch\demo\src\main\resources\text">
            <poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
   </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
   <channel id="inboundFiles"/> 
   <int:service-activator input-channel="inboundFiles" ref="inboundFileProcessor" />
       <int:annotation-config/>
         <context:component-scan base-package="filetransfer"/>
    </beans:beans>
```

my inboundFileProcessor.java

```
    package filetransfer;
    import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    //import org.springframework.stereotype.s

    @Component
    public class InboundFileProcessor {

        @ServiceActivator
            public void onNewFileArrival( String headerValue,Object payload)
             {
               System.out.printf("A new file has arrived deposited into " + "the accounting folder at the absolute " +   "path %s \n", headerValue);
                 }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `xsi:schemaLocation`, you didn't include the locations for `xmlns:file` and `xmlns:int`.

Comment: It's generally easier to use an IDE (such as STS - eclipse with spring plugins or IDEA) to maintain the schema namespace/location configuration. You have the `int` namespace but not the `file` schema location.